# Can every curve be written as $f(x)=g(y)$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Does every irreducible curve admit an equation of the form $f(x)=g(y)$, where $f$ and $g$ are polynomials?  What if we allow $f$ and $g$ to be rational functions?

Actually, I'd like to understand this in the presence of an additional constraint: if we're given a finite cover of curves $\pi\colon C\to\mathbb{P}^1$, do we expect there to be a cover $\phi\colon C\to\mathbb{P}^1$ and rational functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that $C$ is isomorphic to $f(x)=g(y)$ and also $f\circ\phi=g\circ\pi$?  In other words, not only is $C$ isomorphic to $f(x)=g(y)$, but this isomorphism can be chosen so that $\pi$ is the projection onto the $y$ coordinate.

This is reminiscent of Chad Schoen's paper "Varieties dominated by product varieties", but I don't see a precise connection between the two.

Comment: what do you mean by "curve"? since you mention a cover $C \to \mathbb{P}^1$, then it is probably a projective curve, but the nature of equation als suggests that you are talking about a plane affine curve.

Comment: I mean a smooth projective curve.  When I refer to "$f(x)=g(y)$", I mean the normalization of its projective closure.

Comment: Is $C$ meant to be *geometrically* irreducible? Is the ground field algebraically closed?  Of characteristic 0?

Comment: Yes, my question is for curves over the complex numbers.

Comment: Welcome, Mike!!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This would contradict the Harris-Mumford(-Eisenbud) theorem that $M_g$ is non-uniruled for $g$ at least $23$.  Let $C$ be a general curve of genus $g$.  If $C$ is in "Zieve form", then it is the normalization of the (almost certainly) singular curve in $\mathbb{CP}^1 \times \mathbb{CP}^1$,
$$D = \{ ([x_0,x_1],[y_0,y_1]) \in \mathbb{CP}^1\times \mathbb{CP}^1 \vert y_0^e f(x_0,x_1) - x_0^dg(y_0,y_1) \}, $$ where $f(x_0,x_1)$, respectively $g(y_0,y_1)$, is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$, resp. $e$, such that $f(0,1)$ and $g(0,1)$ are nonzero (or else the defining polynomial factors to a simpler form).  By direct computation, the singular points occur where $[x_0,x_1]$ is a multiple root of $f(x_0,x_1)$ and $[y_0,y_1]$ is a multiple root of $g(y_0,y_1)$ or the point is $([0,1],[0,1])$.  Moreover, at each point, the local analytic type of the singularity is the same as the plane curve with equation $y^n-x^m$, where $m$, resp. $n$, is the vanishing order of $f(x_0,x_1)$, resp. $g(y_0,y_1)$ at that point.  In particular, the "delta invariant" depends only on $(m,n)$.  Thus, if you "deform" $f(x_0,x_1)$ and $g(y_0,y_1)$ so that the number and type of multiple roots remains constant, then the normalizations of the corresponding curves in $\mathbb{CP}^1\times \mathbb{CP}^1$ remain of genus $g$.  However, the family of such deformations of $(f,g)$ is a rational variety.  Precisely, if you write
$$ f(x_0,x_1) = (x_1-a_1x_0)^{m_1}(x_1-a_2x_0)^{m_2}\cdots (x_1-a_rx_0)^{m_r}, $$ with $(a_1,\dots,a_r)$ pairwise distinct, 
then the deformation space for $f$ is just a Zariski open subset of the affine space with coordinates $(a_1,\dots,a_r)$, and similarly for $g(x_0,x_1)$. Since $M_g$ is non-uniruled, this is a contradiction: there is only the constant morphism from a rational variety to $M_g$ whose image contains the general point parameterizing $C$.

**Edit.** Mike also asks whether this could be true if $f$ and $g$ are rational functions rather than polynomial functions.  This is equivalent to replacing the defining equation above in $\mathbb{CP}^1 \times \mathbb{CP}^1$ by the more general equation
$$
g_0(y_0,y_1)f_1(x_0,x_1) - f_0(x_0,x_1)g_1(y_0,y_1),
$$
where $f_0$, $f_1$ are homogeneous of degree $d$ with no common factor, and where $g_0$, $g_1$ are homogeneous of degree $d$ with no common factor.  The same observations apply: the number and types of singularities depend only on the number and multiplicities of the roots of $f_0$, $f_1$, $g_0$ and $g_1$.  By varying those (distinct, likely repeated) roots as in the previous paragraph, one gets a morphism from a rational, quasi-projective variety to $M_g$.  By Harris-Mumford(-Eisenbud), the only such morphism is constant if the image contains a general point of $M_g$.

Comment: I'm totally going to start saying "Harris and Mumford proved that the generic genus g curve is not Zieve."

Comment: There is a geometric question (I believe inspired by arithmetic questions of Nick Katz): what is the maximal-dimensional uniruled or rationally connected subvariety of $M_g$.  So far the biggest subvarieties are moduli spaces of trigonal curves.  Perhaps moduli of Zieve curves are a contender(?).

Comment: Suppose you restrict attention to curves defined over Q? Is the result still true, and can you exhibit an example? What about the Klein quartic for example? I believe its Jacobian is a factor of the
Jacobian of the Fermat curve of degree 7, but it's not clear to me
whether it is a model of some f(x)=g(y).

Comment: @paul: I don't know, and that is a good question.  I have seen examples due to Zarhin of curves over $\mathbb{Q}$ that have simple Jacobian.  However, I do not see how to prove that Zieve curves have non-simple Jacobian.  Careful bookkeeping of the relation between the multiplicities $m_i$ above, the genus $g$, and the dimension of the corresponding parameter space *might* help; for instance, if for each genus $g$ there are only finitely many possibilities for the sequence of multiplicities.  Then the Zieve curves would live in a proper, closed subvariety of $M_g$.

Comment: @paul: I just remembered the Lang and Vojta conjectures about rational curves and rational points on varieties of general type.  According to the conjectures, there is a proper, closed subvariety of $M_g$ that contains <B>all</B> rational curves in $M_g$.  This strongly suggests that there are only finitely many sequences of multiplicities $(m_i)$ that give Zieve curves of genus $g$.  I bet we could bound these sequences, and then use that to find a curve of genus $g$ defined over some number field that is not a Zieve curve.

Comment: @jason: I don't understand how there could be finitely many sequences of multiplicities for a fixed genus.  Wouldn't this imply that there are only finitely many possibilities for $d$ and $e$ for a fixed genus?

Comment: @michael:  Yes, this would imply that there are only finitely many choices of $d$ and $e$.  So perhaps the guess is wrong.  There are two possible explanations consistent with Lang-Vojta.  First, there could be "inclusions" among the subvarieties of $M_g$, i.e., it could happen that every curve that is Zieve for some $(d,e)$ is automatically Zieve for infinitely many other choices.  The second explanation is that there is some other (non-generic) algebraic property (perhaps a condition on extra endomorphisms of the Jacobian) such that every Zieve curve has this property.  

Comment: @jason: your "inclusions" idea works in the hyperelliptic case, namely, the curve $y^2=f(x)$ is isomorphic to $y^2=f(x)h(x)^2$ for any $h$.  It seems conceivable that all examples where $\max(d,e)$ is sufficiently large compared to $g$ might behave similarly to the hyperelliptic ones.


Comment: Incidentally, in the literature, curves of the form $g(x)=h(y)$ are called "variables separated curves".

Answer (score 4):

I think that the answer is no.

Here is a somewhat related problem. Every curve curve $C$ of genus >0, has meromorphic functions $x,y$ on it which are
not related by any equation of the form $f(x)=g(y)$.
I denote by $(x)=(x)^+-(x)^-$ the principal divisor of an element $x$,
zeros minus poles.
If $x$ and $y$ are two elemets of the field of meromorphic functions on $C$, related by $f(x)=g(y)$,
where $f,g$ are ratonal functions,
then the divisors of poles of $x$ and $y$ are related as follows:
$$m(x)^-\sim n(y)^-,$$
where $\sim$ means the usual equivalence of divisors.
(Two dividors $d$ and $e$ are equivalent if $d=e+(z)$). And $m,n$ are degrees of $f,g$.

Now the factor of the set of all divisors over this equivalent equation
is a torus of dimension $g$ ($g$ is the genus of $C$). We only need the fact that it is
uncountable for $g>0$. So
we can always find incommensurable divisors of the form $(x)^-$ and $(y)^-$.
These $x$ and $y$ are related by some polynomial relation $F(x,y)=0$, but cannot be related
by an equation of the form $f(x)=g(y)$.

This solution was explained me by Drinfeld in 1980 when I asked him more
general question: Can every algebraic relation $F(x,y)=0$ be obtained
from a chain $x=x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n=y$ where $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$
are related by $f_i(x_i)=f_{i+1}(x_{i+1})$, with some rational functions
$f_i$, by elimination of $x_2,...x_{n-1}$? The answer is no, for the same reason).

Comment: How about over countable ground fields like $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$?

Comment: Hi Alex, you seem to be showing that if $g>0$, $x,y$ can be chosen so that $f(x)=g(y)$ cannot hold. But the question is whether $x,y$ can be  chosen so that such a relation does hold. It is certainly possible sometimes,
e.g. when $C$ is hyperelliptic. I suspect it is false for generic $C$, however.

Comment: Thanks Alex.  But I agree with Donu: you showed that for most choices of $\pi\colon C\to\mathbb{P}^1$ and $\phi\colon C\to\mathbb{P}^1$, there do not exist nonconstant polynomials $f$ and $g$ such that $f\circ\phi=g\circ\pi$.  Whereas my question is whether this can happen for *every* choice of $\phi$ and $\pi$, subject to the additional constraint that $f(x)=g(y)$ is irreducible.

Comment: Also, although you said that $f$ and $g$ are rational functions, your identity of pole divisors only follows if $f$ and $g$ are polynomials.  But under additional hypotheses one can obtain your conclusion for rational functions $f$ and $g$.  For instance, this follows if $C$ contains points $\alpha,\beta$ such that $\phi(\alpha)=\phi(\beta)$, $\pi(\alpha)=\pi(\beta)$, and the ratio of the ramification indices of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ under $\pi$ is different from the analogous ratio under $\phi$.  Variants of this argument are in my paper with Beals and Wetherell in Israel J.Math.

Comment: Michael, on your second comment: if $f$ is a rational function, not necessary a polynomial, then $(f(x))^-\sim d(x)^-$ where $d$ is the degree. Here $\sim$ is the equivalence, not equality. 

Donu, and Michael (first comment): I agree, I gave a solution of a slightly different problem. I edited my answer.

Comment: Correction: generic curves of genus $g$ depend on $3g-3$ parameters.

Comment: Perhaps this is the same objection raised by Donu and Mike, but there are several problems with this answer.  First of all, a generic curve depends on 3g-3 parameters, not g parameters.  More importantly, although the arithmetic genus of the image curve in $\mathbb{P}^2_{\mathbb{C}}$ is quadratic in $d$, the image may be very singular.  Thus the geometric genus of the normalization may be much smaller than $d$.  So I do not see any very easy "parameter count" that rules this out.  Probably a better approach is to argue that such curves have non-simple Jacobians.  

Comment: @pranavk: if $A$ is a (non-zero) Abelian variety over $k=\bar{\mathbf Q}$, the rank of $A(k)$ is infinite. Consequently, if $C$ is a curve over $k$, one may find effective divisors of arbitrary degree $D,E$ such that $D-E$ has degree zero, but is not torsion. If $\deg(D)>2g$, Riemann-Roch implies that $D$ is the divisor of zeroes of some function $x$, and same for $E={\rm div}^-(y)$. Then $x$ and $y$ are not related by an equation of the form $f(x)=g(y)$.