# Complex curves covered by smooth plane curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, algebraic-curves

**Question:** Is it true that for every smooth compact complex curve $C$ there exists a smooth curve $C'$ in $\mathbb CP^2$ that admits a non-trivial morphism (i.e. holomorphic map) $C'\to C$?

**Motivation.**  Unfortunately, I don't know yet any application for a positive answer to this question. But a negative answer to this question would solve in negative a great question of Francesco Polizzi: [Surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^3$ with isolated singularities](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32938/surfaces-in-mathbbp3-with-isolated-singularities)

Indeed, here is a simple exercise:

**Exercise.** Suppose that $C$ is a smooth curve that is not covered by any smooth plane curve. Then the surface $C\times \mathbb CP^1$ is not birational to any surface in $\mathbb CP^3$ with isolated singularities.

Comment: Do you know if this is true for $C$ a hyperelliptic curve of genus 2 or 3?

Comment: @Piotr If $C: y^2=f(x)$ is hyperelliptic with $f$ of even degree $2n$, then $y^{2n}=f(x)$ is smooth and covers $C$. I suspect the answer to the general question is no, but I don't know how to do it. Maybe the answer that Jason Starr gave to a recent question of Mike Zieve will work here too.

Comment: I would be happy with any counter-example but after some thinking it seems to me that the answer to this question might be positive...

Comment: I don't know the answer, and this actually sounds difficult.  Obviously, even when $C$ has general moduli among genus $g$ curves, a finite cover $C'$ does not need to have general moduli.  This question does vaguely remind me of work of Bogomolov and Tschinkel: every curve over the algebraic closure of a finite field has a finite cover that is also an etale cover of a (fixed) hyperelliptic curve.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I made a mistake, my attempted answer is wrong.  It was just the same as @Felipe's comment, namely, that Jason Starr's answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/118117/can-every-curve-be-written-as-fxgy) might apply here too.  But it doesn't.  Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Dear Zieve I would like to know why you can deform $C'$ in the way you descibe. I don't see this.

Comment: After some thinking I don't see any (non-superficial) relation between the question you cite and my question, so I would like to ask you give details on how you want to deform $C'$ with its morphism.

Comment: @Michael: In principle it is possible that each curve og genus $g$ can be covered by a plane curve, but these mappings do not "glue" into a dominant rational mapping from the space of plane curves of a given degree onto `$M_g$`.

Comment: Really?  Then I take it back.  I thought it would be straightforward to get that, if there were a morphism from a smooth plane curve of degree $d$ to a generic genus-$g$ curve, then there is a family of morphisms from a Zariski-open subset of degree-$d$ plane curves to genus-$g$ curves.  If that's not true, then I was wrong.

Comment: Michael, I don't see how you would use in your reasoning the fact that genus $g$ curve is generic. If you remove this assumption, it is very easy to construct a counterexample to that fact that you have assumed. Namely, the space of  genus $3$ curves that admit a morphism to an elliptic curve is Zariski dense (in the moduli space $M_3$ of all genus $3$ curves), but it is by no means open. Since degree four curves in $\mathbb CP^3$ from a Zariski dense subset of $M_3$ we see a contradiction.  

Comment: Sorry in the last comment I meant that degree four curves in $\mathbb CP^2$ form a Zariski OPEN (not only dense) subset in $M_3$.